# Arithmetic error in Java

Tags: java

I recently started learning Java, and I am now trying to solve some Eulerproject problems.

The task is: **What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?**

I was able to create this code, but I get an error:

Code

```
package exercises;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Euler3 {

    // Main code
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.println( getPrimeFactors(15) );
    }

    // Code for breaking a number to prime factors
    public static ArrayList getPrimeFactors(int n){

        ArrayList factors = new ArrayList();

        int d = 2;

        while(n > 1 ){
            while(n%d == 0 ){
                factors.add(d);
                n /= d;
            }
            d +=d;
        }

        return factors;
    }

}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at exercises.Euler3.getPrimeFactors(Euler3.java:22)
    at exercises.Euler3.main(Euler3.java:9)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Your logic appears to be incorrect. It will only divide by powers of 2, and eventually you get a overflow and it tries to divide by 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a very naive solution, try changing the line `d += d` to `d += 1`.

Answer (score 3):

Your `d` is overflowing, I printed `n` and `d` inside `while (n > 1)`:

```
    15 2
    15 4
    15 8
    15 16
    15 32
    15 64
    15 128
    15 256
    15 512
    15 1024
    15 2048
    15 4096
    15 8192
    15 16384
    15 32768
    15 65536
    15 131072
    15 262144
    15 524288
    15 1048576
    15 2097152
    15 4194304
    15 8388608
    15 16777216
    15 33554432
    15 67108864
    15 134217728
    15 268435456
    15 536870912
    15 1073741824
    15 -2147483648
    15 0
```

I think the solution is `d++`, not `d+=d` -- right now you are only checking powers of two, not all consecutive integers.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your d is crossing `Integer.Max` limit and overflowing.